# Where is Database project in VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I want to add a database project to my VS 2015 solution but this type of project is nowhere to be found - was it removed from VS 2015? By the way, I have SQL Server Data Tools installed.

Comment: It is at the same place as in VS2013. What do you see in `Other Languages -> SQL Server` node?

Comment: @IlyaChumakov - oh, it's under Other languages now. Thank you! You can make it into an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Why not, i did it. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in `Templates -> Other Languages -> SQL Server` node.

P.S. Easy to find in `Ctrl+E` search box.